# why is android emulator on local network offline?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, portforwarding

I am developing an android application on android studio. but because of my hardware limits I'd like to test the results through an android studio emulator which is on another computer in my local network.
I've read the tutorial on [this page](http://www.41post.com/5003/programming/android-adb-remote-emulator-access) :

I did all of the steps on the page and I can see the device on android studio (on the my remote pc) but it appears to be **offline** .
any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tutorial:
https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home
Best Regards,
SanatiSharif